# Exclude keywords in Twitter Streaming API

Tags: api, twitter, streaming, keyword

Currently, I am using the Twitter streaming API to get realtime tweets for certain keywords. However, I would like to skip tweets that are irrelevant before getting them.

With the Search API I can search for "hello -john" so I only get tweets that contain the word hello, but not John or I can search for "hello Maria OR Andrew" so I get only tweets that contain the word hello AND either Maria or Andrew.

With the Streaming API, I can only give keywords but is there a way I can use -john or things like OR in these keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to exclude keywords via the streaming API.  [The docs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods) only specify the ability to add keywords to the search but not exclude.  You'll need to filter words out in your code.