# Is it possible to perform a NOT search using the Twitter streaming API through Tweepy?

Tags: tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["aids","hiv","hiv aids"])
```

track=["aids","hiv"] gives me, aids OR hiv

track=["aids hiv"] gives, aids AND hiv.

But, what do we do for NOT ?

Comment: Already asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465757/exclude-keywords-in-twitter-streaming-api . The answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's API filter and track has not a specific case for the NOT operator, probably a not query will tend to return too many results and being computationally heavy.
Tweepy mimics the Twitter API filter and track, so you have no way to do a NOT in the query.

The track/filter are documented here: 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters

What you can do is delete the streams you don't need after you get them based on the tag.